# Whats in SDL.dll?

Tags: sdl

I am new to SDL, and I am just curious why does sdl use static and dynamic libraries? I mean, what functions are in sdl.dll, and why is it linked dynamically instead of statically? Thanks.

Comment: Buh? It's linked dynamically for the same reasons that **any** library would be linked dynamically...

Comment: "Daddy, why is the sky blue?" / "Oh, honey, it's blue for the same reasons that *any* sky might be blue."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SDL.dll` contains implementations of all of the functions that you use from SDL, such as `SDL_Init()` and `SDL_SetVideoMode()`. It's linked dynamically to allow drop-in replacement of the library with a newer version, without breaking compatibility with existing applications—the SDL *interface* does not change nearly as often as the *implementation*. Dynamic libraries provide decoupling between interface and implementation, at the cost of whatever it takes to load them dynamically: searching for a file, loading it, complaining if it's not available, and so on.

An application is more modular using dynamic libraries, and the executable will tend to remain small. It is possible to link statically against SDL, under which circumstances the size of your executable will include the (modest) size of the SDL library, and upgrading to a newer version of SDL will require recompiling your application.

Comment: Do you know, how to link SDL.lib (dll) statically? I know, that target .exe file will have volume of DLL (300kB), but for me is much better to manipulate with one exe file. I am developing under Pelles C environment. SDL implementation is very simple: copy .h .lib. dll files into existing structure as in LCC or another win32 compiler.